# How to animate ng-leave the correct element in a ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs, ng-animate

I'm having a really cool animation on ng-enter in a ng-repeat.
However, when removing a specific item in the repeat, I also want it to leave with a cool animation. Each item has a delete button, which deletes the item from the array.

```
bill.items = _.reject(bill.items,item);
```

The problem is that the animation happens only for the last item in the repeat, regardless of which item I'm trying to remove.
I guess this is just a problem of the rendering, but was wandering if someone has a hack for it. I tried some but no luck yet...

Comment: Shouldn't the second argument to _.reject be a predicate function? Are you using 'track by' in your ng-repeat?

Comment: No. Reject works by passing the object you want to remove too. I am using track by $index in this repeater why?

Comment: For some reason I just assumed it was Underscore's reject you were using, but I guess it's Lo-Dash?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is the expected result when using `track by $index`.

If you for example have ten items in the collection, the last item will have $index 9. Remove one, doesn't matter which one, and the last one will now have $index 8. This means there no longer is an element with $index 9, and as you are tracking by $index, the associated DOM element that previously had $index 9 will be removed.

You either need to remove the `track by` or track by a property actually related to specific element.

Example:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items track by item.id">
```

**Demo with track by $index:** http://plnkr.co/edit/Y2aGC2GOEIIDoxuVQmCA?p=preview

**Demo with track by object property:** http://plnkr.co/edit/xGhQ3mYIhvmwZWxnEer1?p=preview